# Extend vlookup to calculate cost of goods

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have sales report from e-shop and need to calculate cost of goods for each order line. Order line can look like one of these:

2x Lavazza Crema e Aroma 1kg - 1x Lavazza Dolce Caffe Crema 1kg

1x Lavazza Vending Aroma Top 1kg - 1x Arcaffe Roma 1Kg - 1x Kimbo - 100% Arabica Top Flavour

So, what I need Excel to do is to take each product, find its cost with vlookup function from another sheet and then multiply it with amount ordered. The issue is that nr of products ordered can vary from 1 to 10+.
I tried to calculate it with VBA, but the code is not working (I didn´t use multiplying at the moment, I know)
Maybe it is possible to solve this problem with excel formulas?

```
Function GoodsCost(str, Optional strDelim As String = " ")
larray = Split(str, strDelim)
Set lookup_range = Worksheets("Products").Range("B:E")
For i = LBound(larray) To UBound(larray)
    skuarray = Split(larray(i), "x ")
    skucost = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(UBound(skuarray), lookup_range, 4, False)
    cost = cost + skucost
Next i
GoodsCost = cost
End Function
```

Comment: Is `2x Lavazza Crema e Aroma 1kg - 1x Lavazza Dolce Caffe Crema 1kg` content of a single cell? Are multiple items separated by dash (-)? Does any product description contain dash(-)? Do you have exact matching product descriptions like `Lavazza Crema e Aroma 1kg`?

Comment: Yes, in a single cell.
Multiple items are separated by dash (-)
Some products contain dash in description :-(
Yes, in products table description matches exactly

Comment: Is quantity always at the start (before the product name) and followed by x?

Comment: Yes, always. I think that it is possible to replace the separator by more unique symbol like "/" or delete all dashes "-" from product names.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like now the problem is solved. Of course, it works only if make an assumption that dashes(-) are not present in product descriptions. But it can be set up in product list. The other opportunity is to use another delimeter (for example "/"). We can use Ctrl+F to find all combinations like "x -" and replace them with "x /")

```
Function GoodsCost(str)
Dim answer As Double
Set Products = Worksheets("Products").Range("B:E")
larray = Split(str, " - ")
For i = LBound(larray) To UBound(larray)
    sku = Split(larray(i), "x ")
    Price = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sku(1), Products, 4, False) * sku(0)
    answer = answer + Price
Next i
GoodsCost = answer
End Function
```

Comment: please check my answer, as it would work even with dashes in the product description. :)

Answer (score 0):

Below you find a UDF (User Defined Function) which you can use in your worksheet. After installing it in a standard code module (VBE names these like "Module1") you can call it from the worksheet like `=CostOfGoods($A2)` where A2 is the cell containing and order line as you have described.

```
Option Explicit

Function CostOfGoods(Cell As Range) As Single
    ' 15 Jan 2018

    Const Delim As String = " - "

    Dim Fun As Single                   ' function return value
    Dim Sale As Variant
    Dim Sp() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim PriceList As Range
    Dim Qty As Single, Price As Single
    Dim n As Integer

    Sale = Trim(Cell.Value)
    If Len(Sale) Then
        Sp = Split(Sale, Delim)
        Do While i <= UBound(Sp)
            If InStr(Sp(i), "x ") = 0 Then
                If Not ConcatSale(Sp, i, Delim) Then Exit Do
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop

        With Worksheets("Products")
            i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            ' price list starts in row 2 (change as required)
            Set PriceList = Range(.Cells(2, "B"), .Cells(i, "E"))
        End With

        For i = 0 To UBound(Sp)
            Qty = Val(Sp(i))
            n = InStr(Sp(i), " ")
            Sp(i) = Trim(Mid(Sp(i), n))
            On Error Resume Next
            Price = Application.VLookup(Sp(i), PriceList, 4, False)
            If Err Then
                MsgBox "I couldn't find the price for" & vbCr & _
                       Sp(i) & "." & vbCr & _
                       "The total cost calculated excludes this item.", _
                       vbInformation, "Price not found"
                Price = 0
            End If
            Fun = Fun + (Qty * Price)
        Next i
    End If

    CostOfGoods = Fun
End Function

Private Function ConcatSale(Sale() As String, _
                            i As Long, _
                            Delim As String) As Boolean
    ' 15 Jan 2018

    Dim Fun As Boolean                  ' function return value
    Dim x As Long, f As Long

    x = UBound(Sale)
    If (i > 0) And (i <= x) Then
        i = i - 1
        Sale(i) = Sale(i) & Delim & Sale(i + 1)
        For f = i + 1 To x - 1
            Sale(f) = Sale(f + 1)
        Next f
        Fun = True
    End If

    If Fun Then ReDim Preserve Sale(x - 1)
    ConcatSale = Fun
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this and it works with dashes in product description:

```
Function GoodsCost(str, Optional strDelim As String = " ")
larray = Split(str, " ")
'split the cell contents by space
Set lookup_range = Worksheets("Products").Range("B:E")
'set lookup range
For i = LBound(larray) To UBound(larray) 'loop through array
nextproduct:
    LPosition = InStr(larray(i), "x") 'find multiplier "x" in string
    If LPosition = Len(larray(i)) Then 'if the last character is x
        If Product <> "" Then GoTo lookitup 'lookup product
        Quantity = larray(i) 'get quantity
    Else
        Product = Product & " " & larray(i) 'concatenate array until we get a full product description to lookup with
    End If
Next i
lookitup:
If Right(Product, 2) = " -" Then Product = Left(Product, Len(Product) - 2)
If Left(Product, 1) = " " Then Product = Right(Product, Len(Product) - 1)
'above trim the Product description to remove unwanted spaces or dashes
cost = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Product, lookup_range, 4, False)
Quantity = Replace(Quantity, "x", "")
GoodsCost = cost * Quantity
MsgBox Product & " @ Cost: " & GoodsCost
Product = ""
If i < UBound(larray) Then GoTo nextproduct
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Regular Expressions to solve this. First it finds in the string were the 'delimiters' are by replacing the `-` with `;` detecting only `-` that are next to a number followed by an `x` (i.e. a multiplier so ignoring `-` in product names). It then splits each of these results into a quantity and the product (again using RegEx). It then finds the product in your data and returns the cost of goods. If there is an error, or the product isn't in your data it returns a `#Value` error to show that there is an issue.

```
Public Function GoodsCost(str As String) As Double
    Dim lookup_range As Range, ProductMatch As Range
    Dim v, Match
    Dim qty As Long
    Dim prod As String
    Dim tmp() As String

    On Error GoTo err

    Set lookup_range = Worksheets("Products").Range("B:E")

    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .ignorecase = True

        .pattern = "(\s\-\s)(?=[0-9]+x)"
        If .test(str) Then
            tmp = Split(.Replace(str, ";"), ";")
        Else
            ReDim tmp(0)
            tmp(0) = str
        End If
        .pattern = "(?:([0-9]+)x\s(.+))"
        For Each v In tmp
            If .test(v) Then
                Set Match = .Execute(v)
                qty = Match.Item(0).submatches.Item(0)
                prod = Trim(Match.Item(0).submatches.Item(1))
                Set ProductMatch = lookup_range.Columns(1).Find(prod)
                If Not ProductMatch Is Nothing Then
                    GoodsCost = GoodsCost + (qty * ProductMatch.Offset(0, 3))
                Else
                    GoodsCost = CVErr(xlErrValue)
                End If
            End If
        Next v
    End With
Exit Function
err:
    GoodsCost = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```